# kubernetes internal network monitoring without any sidecar

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, istio, calico, linkerd

I have k8s cluster with 1000 of services and high internal network communication.
I want to monitor all HTTP requests (status code, response time, ...) between them.
I already tried istio and Linkerd but both need sidecar containers and cause performance issue.
Linkerd doesn't have full time monitoring and istio send 502 some times.

Can I get internal network logs like nginx syslogs?

Comment: Did you check `prometheus`?

Comment: Yes i did, but nothing show

Comment: Istio is known to have performance issues, and I'm curious to know what kind of performance issues you saw with Linkerd? What kind of full time monitoring are you looking for?